# Multiple for loops in expect script

Tags: shell, loops, unix, expect

Hi I am not that good in loops. Can some one help me for sftp process. The script should read 2 files, one have filenames and another one has localpaths. The script should do a loop fist go into path1 and get file1 from source to target. BUT IT IS GETTING ONLY ONE FILE. I mean the script or loop is executing the loop only one time. Can you guys help me with this. Or instead of for loop can anyone write in someother way. Thanks in Advance..!!

```
The bkupdirs file contains:
bkupdir1
bkupdir2
bkupdir3
dkupdir4
The backupfiles_list file contains:
bkupfile1
bkupfile2
bkupfile3
bkupfile4 

#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set sourceServer servername;
set f [open "/scripts/bkupdirs"]
set localbkuppaths [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
# Get the commands to run, one per line
set f [open "/dba/backupfiles_list"]
set srcbkupfiles [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach lbkuppath $localbkuppaths {
    spawn sftp id1@$sourceServer
    expect "password:"
    send "passwd\n";
    expect "sftp>"
    send "lcd $lbkuppath\n" 

# Iterate over the commands
foreach srcbkupfile $srcbkupfiles {
    expect "sftp>"
    send "get $srcbkupfile\n"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "bye\n"
}

# Tidy up
#    send "exit\n"
#    expect eof
#       interact
close
}

After the first iteration successfully it is not going to second value or 2nd iteration and have error msg like this:
send "bye\n"..."
("foreach" body line 10)
invoked from within
"foreach lbkuppath $localbkuppaths {
spawn sftp id1@$sourceServer
expect "password:"
send "passwd\n";
    expect "sftp>"
    send "lcd $l..."
(file "/db2dba/d1/master_scripts/sftpfull" line 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set files to different variables like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set f1 [open "/scripts/bkupdirs"]
set localbkuppaths [split [read $f1] "\n"]
close $f1
# Get the commands to run, one per line
set f2 [open "/dba/backupfiles_list"]
set srcbkupfiles [split [read $f2] "\n"]
close $f2
```